# How do you solve for the mean in a Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, quantile

I am working on a problem and am a little bit stuck on how to solve it.

The problem: Find a Normal Distribution with SD 2.5 and 5% Quantile at -15.2.

What I have done so far:
$$X=\mu+2.5Z$$
$$.05=P(\mu+2.5Z\le-15.2)$$
How do we reduce this further? It looks like we have two unknowns.

I know that Q 95% = 1.645 based on the Z Table and that this would correspond to 5% being $-1.645$

Also, $\sigma^2=6.25$, so I know it needs to be something along the lines of $X\sim\mathcal N(x, 6.25)$. I am a little bit confused on the next step though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate the expression inside $P()$:
$$\mu+2.5Z\le-15.2$$
$$Z\le\frac{-15.2-\mu}{2.5}$$
But we know that the critical $Z$-value that will give the 5th percentile is $-1.645$. Thus
$$-1.645=\frac{-15.2-\mu}{2.5}$$
$$\mu=-11.0875$$

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot more sense now!